# Redcarpet Markdown Conversion Method, NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown, redcarpet

Working on an assignment here. Was just introduced to Redcarpet and the Markdown conversion Method.

This was placed inside my Helper:

```
def markdown_to_html(markdown)
  renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
  extensions = { fenced_code_blocks: true }
  redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
  (redcarpet.render markdown).html_safe
end
```

And I could call the method in my views like so:

**views/posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<h1><%= markdown_to_html @post.title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p><%= markdown_to_html @post.body %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have to do the following:

> The goal is to render markdown like so:

```
<%= post.markdown_title %>
<%= post.markdown_body %>
```

> Add Post#markdown_title and Post#markdown_body to Post:
>
> Create a private Post#render_as_markdown method that markdown_title
>   and markdown_body can call. This will keep the markdown_title and
>   markdown_body DRY.
>
> Remove the markdown_to_html method from application_helper.rb.
>
> Update your views to use the Post#markdown_title and
>   Post#markdown_body methods.

I have so far attempted to do this:

**models/post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic

  # Sort by most recent posts first
  default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }

  # Post must have at least 5 characters in the title
  validates :title, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  # Post must have at least 20 characters in the body
  validates :body, length: { minimum: 20 }, presence: true
  # Post must have an associated topic and user
  validates :topic, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true

  def render_as_markdown(markdown)
    renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
    extensions = { fenced_code_blocks: true }
    redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
    (redcarpet.render markdown).html_safe
  end

  private 

  def markdown_title(markdown)
    render_as_markdown(markdown).title
  end

  def markdown_body(markdown)
    render_as_markdown(markdown).body
  end
end
```

If we go back to my **views/posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<h1><%= @post.title.markdown_title %></h1>
```

Will render:

> NoMethodError in Posts#show

```
undefined method `markdown_title' for "chopper mag":String
Extracted source (around line #1):

<h1><%= @post.title.markdown_title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p><%= markdown_to_html @post.body %>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I rectify this issue?

Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here. First, you've made `markdown_title` a private method in your class, so it won't be accessible in your view. You need to remove the word `private` from above your `markdown_title` and `markdown_body` methods in order to make them available to your views. In addition, since the requirement is to make `render_as_markdown` private, you need to move that *below* the `private` keyword. Long story short, your methods should be structured in your class as follows:

```
def markdown_title(markdown)
  ...
end

def markdown_body(markdown)
  ...
end

private 

def render_as_markdown(markdown)
  ...
end
```

Second, if you take a look at how `markdown_title` and `markdown_body` are supposed to be called (below), they don't take in any parameters.

```
<%= post.markdown_title %>
<%= post.markdown_body %>
```

So, your `Post` object methods `markdown_title` and `markdown_body` shouldn't take in any parameters. And since they are called on a specific object of class `Post`, they don't need to take in any.

```
def markdown_title
  render_as_markdown(self.title)
end

def markdown_body
  render_as_markdown(self.body)
end
```

Then, in your view, you can use `markdown_title` and `markdown_body` according to the requirements:

```
<h1><%= @post.markdown_title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p><%= @post.markdown_body %>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your explanation on what I was doing wrong and how it was supposed to be. This worked perfectly. Cheers!